# Sending FUA requests using libaio on Linux

Tags: linux, aio, block-device

I'm trying to access a block device (say /dev/sdb) using libaio.
I works correctly, but I was wondering how to perform FUA (Force Unit Access) using the API of libaio.

I must say the documentation I found on the subject is quite poor, hope one of you will be able to help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, unfortunately.  The interface is too limited.  But what you should be able to do is use the `SG_IO ioctl()` for `SYNCHRONIZE CACHE (10)` or `(16)`.  That is, if your device supports the command.  `SYNCHRONIZE CACHE` lets you instruct the device to commit a range of logical blocks to the medium.

See the manpage for the `sg_sync` command: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/sg_sync.8.html

And download the latest `sg3_utils` source here: http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sg3_utils.html (as of now, version 1.41 http://sg.danny.cz/sg/p/sg3_utils-1.41.tar.xz).  Look at the sg_sync command source to see how the ioctl is invoked.

`ioctl(SG_IO)` blocks, but there is a way to transact these commands with non-blocking I/O.  Refer to the SCSI Generic HOWTO: http://sg.danny.cz/sg/p/sg_v3_ho.html